# Angular JS loading screen and page animation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS for a current project and my site has around 6 - 7 pages. I am using the /#/ navigation scheme and I would like to introduce a loading/please wait screen while the XHR request is off getting the template.

Once the template has been downloaded, I would like to invoke a page transition, but I am really stumped as to how to structure this or execute it.

Can this be done simply or is there any examples that are around?

Comment: @ruhanbidart said : "We have another good example in this github repo: https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-spinner "

Answer (score 17):

## To Show a loading message while AngularJs is Bootstrapped

You can use [`ngCloak`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak)

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Example CSS

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak
{
    display: none;
}

#splash-page.ng-cloak  /*<-- This has higher specificity so it can display a splash screen*/
{
    display: block;
}
```

## To Show a loading message via a promise

We actulaly use the a [promise tracker](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker) that lets you track promises and display a message if they are active which is located on [github](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker)

From the demo:

```
  <div ng-show="pizzaTracker.active()" style="background:pink;">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
      Loading Pizza
      <br />{{pizzaPercent() | number:2}}%
    </h1>
  </div>
```

And to register a `$http` to the promise tracker

```
$http.get('flavor.json', { tracker: 'pizza' });
```

Comment: So, `ng-cloak` will hide whatever element I put it on and Angular will remove this directive once the remote view is loaded? Im struggling to understand how I can use this, if I hide my view, I still need to display a 'loading' element (which will ultimately be a full-screen element) and once the view is loaded, I then need to hide the loading view.

Comment: Gave an example of `ngCloak` for how we display a splash screen while angularjs is loading up.

Comment: Thank you for updating your example, but I am still confused, sorry if there is something fundamental that I dont understand, im still learning Angular. With you example, if I was to add ng-cloak to my ng-view `<div class="span12" ng-view ng-cloak>` that would hide that span until the scene was compiled, then it would show it. Now, if I add a new `<div id="splash-page">` as the parent of the first `span` that may work, but I dont know how it would then disappear once the scene is loaded

Comment: @Mark Can I use the promise tracker with $resource?

Answer (score 12):

I've solved this problem by writing custom HTTP Interceptor. Here is sample code:

```
var app = angular.module('yourapp', ['loadingService']);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    var spinnerFunction = function (data, headers) {
        $('#loading').show();
        return data;
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
});

angular.module('loadingService', [],
    function ($provide) {

        $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $window) {
            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(function (response) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    return response;
                }, function (response) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
            };
        });
    });
```

**NOTE**: There should be an element with the ID of `loading` in the DOM.

Comment: Hey Thanks! Will this also affect regular http GET/POST Ajax requests? I would only want the loading screen for page navigation.

Comment: Yes, it affects all HTTP requests. So it seems you need other solution.

Comment: Hi, while your solution works, it's a very bad design idea to reference dom elements from services or configuration.

Comment: @Spock then why don't you give one that's better?

Comment: A directive could be used with `ng-show` for showing and hiding.

Comment: @ibeitia: do you know how that would be implemented?