# Why isn't my page loading when I use css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have my page at this site: [www.rootscope.in](http://www.rootscope.in/)

When I use css, particularly this one below:

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(assets/img/icons/loader.svg) no-repeat center center #fe9d68;
    background-size: 60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <!--main content-->
        <div id="wrap">
            <div ui-view="content" id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular routing:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

// For any unmatched url, redirect to /login
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
        content: {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: function ($scope) {
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Some of the script used in this template:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.easydropdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.viewportchecker.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

I have this line in the script tag:

```
$('.loader').fadeOut('slow'); // End Loader
```

The page keep showing the loading svg icon animation. When I inspect the page in chrome and remove the `.loader` class, the page loads but with some styles missing. I could have checked for errors but I purchased this html/css template from a site and I applied angular to it. I don't understand what is problem with `.loader class`

Comment: Show more code, there is not enough info that we can help

Comment: @MehdiDehghani All the code is in the website. You can check source.

Comment: `.loader` element is being downloaded dynamically by angular. When you give the command to "End Loader" it still doesn't exists.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo I didn't get you

Comment: I'm afraid but you need to put relevant codes here. it's the way that Stackoverflow works.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I put the code that is causing the issue. Rest of code is a lot to put into question so I shortened it

Comment: At least show the complete code that you used for `fading out` the `loader`. btw I think if you using `setTimeout` your code will work. if so, you need to change the way for deal with the loader.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani loader in html is just like this: `<div class="loader"></div>`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani `$('.loader').fadeOut('slow');`

Comment: Can you change the code to `setTimeout(function(){$('.loader').fadeOut('slow');}, 5000);` and report the result?

Comment: Related [How to do preloader for `ng-view` in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107459/how-to-do-preloader-for-ng-view-in-angular-js)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I tried the `setTimeout()` but it doesn't load the `.loader` at all and styles go missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123112/discussion-between-mehdi-dehghani-and-satyadev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common issue is to load scripts after DOM is loaded, but before AngularJS runs script to load the template page.

You should only hide ".loader" after Angular. Simplest solution (but not scalable) is just to put it in the angular controller:

```
function controller($scope){
   $('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the loader element is not found on the document load because content is not yet loaded. 
So use setTimeout here for few seconds then it works prefectly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It's not the solution, because maybe the load time be more than 1000